# Plot of a function involving an integral and value changing parameters

Tags: python, scipy, integration, plotting, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the cross section with respect to the photon energy  $h\nu$ but for $\gamma = 1.0, 1.2, 2.0 $ in the same axes

$\sigma = \left[\left(\frac{\xi_{eff}}{\xi_{0}}\right)^2 \frac{n_r}{\varepsilon}\right]\frac{4\pi}{3}\alpha_{fs}h\nu|\frac{1}{2}\frac{R}{2^\beta \Gamma(\beta + 1)}\int_{0}^\infty \left(\gamma\rho\right)^{2\beta}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\gamma^2\rho^2}\gamma^2\rho^2d\rho|^{2}  \frac{\hbar\Gamma_f}{\left(\lambda_{01} - \lambda_{00} - h\nu\right)^2 + \left(\hbar\Gamma_f\right)^2} $

where

$
\lambda_{00} = 2\gamma^2\left(\beta + 1\right) - \frac{\gamma^4}{4}
$

e
$
\lambda_{01} = 2\gamma^2\left(\beta + 3\right) - \frac{\gamma^4}{4}
$

are the energies of the final and ground states, and 
$
\beta =\sqrt{ \left(m - \Phi\right)^2) - \frac{\gamma^4}{4} }
$

Here' s my attempt to solve this problem in Python:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import gamma
from scipy.constants import  pi, alpha
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Constants
epsilon = 13.1 #dielectric constant of the material
gamma_C = 0.5 # donor impurity linewidth 
nr = 3.2 #refractive index of semiconductor
m = 0 # magnetic number
flux = 0  # Phi in eqn 8 magnetic flux
R = 5  #radius of the qunatum ring in nm
r = np.linspace(0, 6 * R)
rho = r / R
m_0 = 0.0067*0.511 # electron effective mass
h = 4.13e-15 # Planck constant in eV
hbar =  6.58e-16 # reduced Planck constant in eV
#Photon energy
h_ni = np.linspace(0, 100/h) #in eV


#Function that calculates the integrand
def func(rho, gama):
    beta = np.sqrt((m - flux)**2 + gama**4/4)
    return ((gama * rho)**2*beta * np.exp(-1/2*(gama * rho)**2) 
         * (gama * rho)**2/2   ) 

def cross_section(h_ni, gama):
    #function that calculates the photoionisation cross sectio
    beta = np.sqrt((m - flux)**2 + gama**4/4)
    Ei = gama**2*(1+beta)-gama**4/2
    Ef = gama**2*(3+beta)-gama**4/2

    return ((nr/epsilon) * 4*pi/3 * alpha * h_ni * 
          R ** 2 / (2**beta * gamma(beta + 1)) * 
          abs(quad(func, 0, np.infty))**2  *
            hbar*gamma_C/(((Ef-Ei-h_ni))**2 + ( hbar*gamma_C)**2))

#Plot

plt.figure();plt.clf()

for gama in [1.0, 1.5, 2.0]:
    plt.plot(h_ni, cross_section(h_ni, gama))
```

But I got the following error

```
   TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'gama'
```

How can I solve this? Any help is welcome.

Comment: I would suggest that you non-dimensionalize your equation since right now you have too much parameters and it is a bit cumbersome to work with.

Comment: Revision 7 of the question got an answer (which seemed to help). Continuing editing and debugging the code on Computational Science SE (as well as on StackOverflow) should not happen. Moreover, revision 7 that got the answer is certainly off-topic, as it is about the syntaxis of the particular functionality in Python.

Comment: So, I did a rollback and closed this question. If while solving this problem you get the question that is more aligned with the computational science aspect, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: Actually, I solved the syntaxis problem, but found several other problems in the computational aspects. I'll ask another question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `func(rho, gamma)` takes two arguments while you pass only one (I think none). That is what your error tells you.

Recheck where you use `func(rho, gamma)` and make sure you pass two arguments.

Comment: Edited the question and removed argument gamma. Now I have a plot but it seem pretty weird.

Comment: @DanielLima don't know why the question is closed. However, you can ask in the comment if there is any problem.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question on StackOverflow. As your problem seems to related to programming error rather than your logic.